# Installing Ubuntu 15.10 with Windows 10 in EFI mode on two harddrives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi

I have just bought a new computer with two hard drives and it came with Windows 10 pre-installed. I decided to install Kubuntu on the second hard drive. The weird thing that struck me from the beginning is that Windows seemed to be installed on /dev/sdb and not, as usual on /dev/sda. Here is the output of `lsblk -o +FSTYPE -o +LABEL -o +PARTLABEL` after the installation.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT PARTLABEL
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk            
├─sda1   8:1    0  29.8G  0 part [SWAP]     
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part            
└─sda5   8:5    0 901.7G  0 part /          
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk            
├─sdb1   8:17   0   260M  0 part            EFI system partition
├─sdb2   8:18   0   128M  0 part            Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb3   8:19   0 930.7G  0 part            Basic data partition
└─sdb4   8:20   0   500M  0 part            Basic data partition
```

The problem is that grub does not seem to be able to recognize Windows or the EFI partition. `sudo update-grub` gives me the following:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

I have tried to follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall) to install grub-efi but now I am getting the following message when running `grub-install /dev/sdb`

```
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
```

I have been working on this the whole afternoon and I am at a loss now. Is it necessary to create a small boot partition on `sdb` and will this solve the problem? Or is there something else I am missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your Windows installation is in EFI mode and your Ubuntu installation is (probably) in BIOS mode. This is a recipe for headaches. There are numerous possible solutions. The two easiest are likely to be:

- *Disable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM)* in the firmware, boot an Ubuntu emergency disk, and run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on the computer. This should install the EFI version of GRUB 2, which should work better than what you've got now.
- If it's not already disabled, disable Secure Boot in your firmware. Then download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a medium from it, and boot it. This should enable you to boot either Windows or Ubuntu. Test both, and if both work, install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package from Ubuntu.

As a side note, disk identification (`/dev/sda` vs. `/dev/sdb`) is somewhat arbitrary, so don't read anything into the fact that Windows is on what Linux identifies as `/dev/sdb`. Such mappings can even vary from one boot to the next, although that level of arbitrariness is uncommon.